# Determining which content was delivered securely and which wasn't

Tags: security, https

I want to know which items on this page:
https://www.ticketwise.nl/123
are delivered securely and which arent.

I receive different notifications in different browsers:
Firefox: No notification
Chrome: shows me a https issue
IE9: Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?

Now, HOW can I see why this notification is shown? I tried sending everything over https, but am now unsure which items ARENT delivered over https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to determain what is being sent over SSL (port 443) and what is not.

Comment: Ok, I installed it and ran it. It seems this is the only item not delivered securely is: host: www.facebook.com 
url: /extern/login_status.php?api_key=259543038899&app_id=259543038899&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-s   <removed for overview>
But on that I have no influence? Could you perhaps check if my fiddler conclusion was correct? (by visiting https://www.ticketwise.nl/123)   thanks!

Comment: @Floran Yeah there is nothing you can do about that unless facebook allows you to set https.

Comment: Ok, well since this is my first time to use Fiddler I am not sure I read everything correctly. If you are familiar with Fiddler, would you be so kind to check if facebook TRULY is the only thing NOT delivered securely (otherwise I will invest in development of that only to find out it wasnt the issue :). Hope you're able to do so! Thanks!