# Facebook Connect over https

Tags: facebook, https

I want users to be able to use Facebook Connect on MY website. And I dont want IE to throw a popup that not all items were delivered securely. This means Facebook has to return code over https to me as well. See this site to see the issue in action: https://www.ticketwise.nl/123

The related issue can be found here: [Determining which content was delivered securely and which wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124013/determining-which-content-was-delivered-securely-and-which-wasnt/6125138)

So my questions are:

1. Is Facebook Connect possible over https?
2. if so: which integration method should I use?

Comment: Just a note, it's not only possible. It'll become a requirement in Oct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. You need to ensure you have a working SSL certificate and then you can log into your Facebook account, go to the Developer application and set a secure URL.

That fixed the warnings for me. However you MUST buy an SSL cert and make sure that is correctly setup. I like GoDaddy's $12.99 SSL certificates: just search in Google and then click the first ad they have.

Comment: I just see this: "Secure Canvas URL", but the canvas URL is needed for when I want to develop an application ON facebook. I just want to use Facebook Connect from my OWN website...I dont see the option to set that secure url on Facebook...where can I find it?

Comment: Ah, for connect on your own website as long as you have an SSL cert it should just work. Do you have an SSL cert and have ssl properly setup? are you requesting the Facebook javascript library with https?